# Javascript : Sort array of object programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following structure:

```
var participant1 = {
    name : "aaa",
} ;

var participant2 = {
    name : "bbb",
} ;

var participant3 = {
    name : "ccc",
} ;
```

And i have an array which contain instances of structure :

```
var array = [participant3, participant1, participant2];
```

How can i sort the array by alphabetical letter of name attribute to get this result :

```
var array = [participant1, participant2, participant3];
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you saying that you want to sort by *name of variable* or by the *name property within the object contained in the variable*?

Comment: You can't; the concept doesn't make much sense. The names of the variables to which those object references are assigned are not in any way an intrinsic part of the objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method:

```
array = array.sort( function(a,b) {
    if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```